# COBOL: Read INPUT from SYSIN and store to variable

Tags: cobol

I am trying to read 3 lines of input from COBOL STDIN and store them to 3 different variables. I plan on using COMPUTE on these inputs to perform a calculation.

I have been looking at TutorialsPoint (I'm teaching myself how to code COBOL), but to no avail.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION. 
PROGRAM-ID. SOLUTION. 

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION. 
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION. 
FILE-CONTROL. 
SELECT SYSIN ASSIGN TO KEYBOARD ORGANIZATION LINE SEQUENTIAL. 

DATA DIVISION. 
    FILE SECTION. 
    FD SYSIN. 
    01 INPUT-LINE PIC X(255).
    88 EOF VALUE HIGH-VALUES.

    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 MEAL-COST PIC 9(2)V9(2).
    01 TIP-PERCENT PIC 9(3).
    01 TAX-PERCENT PIC 9(3).

PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
    OPEN INPUT SYSIN 
    READ SYSIN
    AT END SET EOF TO TRUE 
    END-READ

    DISPLAY MEAL-COST
    DISPLAY TIP-PERCENT
    DISPLAY TAX-PERCENT

    CLOSE SYSIN.

STOP RUN.
```

The inputs will be of form:

12.00 
5 
20

And the result will be an integer (in the sense of other programming languages).

The only way I see storing the variables is to, upon each sequential iteration, have a counter and store it to each variable (MEAL-COST, TIP-PERCENT, TAX-PERCENT). However, perhaps there is an easier way to do this?

This is what I've done, but I believe there is yet a better way to get the input and store them into the correct variables. If anyone has any suggestions, that would be much appreciated.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION. 
PROGRAM-ID. SOLUTION. 

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION. 
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION. 
FILE-CONTROL. 
SELECT SYSIN ASSIGN TO KEYBOARD ORGANIZATION LINE SEQUENTIAL. 

DATA DIVISION. 
    FILE SECTION. 
    FD SYSIN. 
    01 INPUT-LINE PIC X(255).
    88 EOF VALUE HIGH-VALUES.

    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 MEAL-COST PIC 9(3)V9(2).
    01 TIP-PERCENT PIC 9(3)V9(2).
    01 TAX-PERCENT PIC 9(3)V9(2).
    01 TIP PIC 9(3)V9(2).
    01 TAX PIC 9(3)V9(2).
    01 TOTAL-COST PIC 9(3)V9(2).
    01 ROUNDED-TOTAL-COST PIC 9(3).
    01 FORMATTED-RESULT PIC Z(3).

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    OPEN INPUT SYSIN
    READ SYSIN
    AT END SET EOF TO TRUE
    NOT AT END
    MOVE INPUT-LINE TO MEAL-COST
    READ SYSIN
    AT END SET EOF TO TRUE
    NOT AT END
    MOVE INPUT-LINE TO TIP-PERCENT
    READ SYSIN
    AT END SET EOF TO TRUE
    NOT AT END
    MOVE INPUT-LINE TO TAX-PERCENT
    END-READ.

    COMPUTE TIP= (MEAL-COST * TIP-PERCENT / 100).
    COMPUTE TAX= (MEAL-COST * TAX-PERCENT / 100).

    COMPUTE TOTAL-COST= MEAL-COST + TIP + TAX.

    COMPUTE ROUNDED-TOTAL-COST ROUNDED = TOTAL-COST.

    MOVE ROUNDED-TOTAL-COST TO FORMATTED-RESULT.

    DISPLAY "The total meal cost is" FORMATTED-RESULT " dollars.". 

    CLOSE SYSIN.

STOP RUN.
```

Comment: I've tried to use ACCEPT as well:  
 
`PROCEDURE DIVISION.`  
    `OPEN INPUT SYSIN`  
    `ACCEPT MEAL-COST`  
    `ACCEPT TIP-PERCENT`  
    `ACCEPT TAX-PERCENT`  
    
    `DISPLAY MEAL-COST`  
    `DISPLAY TIP-PERCENT`  
    `DISPLAY TAX-PERCENT`       
      
    `CLOSE SYSIN.`

Comment: You don't use OPEN when using ACCEPT. ACCEPT data-name. Depending on your compiler, your input will be converted, or not. So, what compiler/OS are you using?

Comment: You likely want to check [intrinsic functions](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/cobol/7580/intrinsic-functions), especially `FUNCTION NUMVAL`, too.

Comment: @BillWoodger, from what I read so far, ACCEPT isn't the best way to go for that,but I was just trying anything I can.

Comment: @BillWoodger also I'm using (OpenCOBOL) 1.1.0, under COBOL 2002.

Comment: @SimonSobisch  I figured out a way to convert between values by using a lot of variable formatting, but perhaps there is an easier way? I happened to have seen a lot of stuff online about creating variables for formatting. Also, I've been able to solve this issue using a (from my understanding) pretty hacky way.

Comment: @qxzsilver Do you just want to get the values from the operator? SYSIN is often used for pipes, otherwise passing these values at command line and reading it or a plain `ACCEPT` is likely a better option.
... and there are not very much reasons to use the outdated (2009) OpenCOBOL 1.1, better use current release candidate or at least the last releases (2014) GnuCOBOL 1.1.

Comment: You are missing a couple of END-READs in your program now. ACCEPT is a perfectly normal way for a PC-based COBOL to interact with the user. There are many specific Language Extensions to ACCEPT, so behaviour can be different between compilers (like is the data "edited" automatically, or do you have to do it yourself, can a screen position be specified, others).

Comment: @BillWoodger If I add in the END-READs, I get the following error:

Error: syntax error, unexpected "NOT END"

That's the reason why I put the current hacky solution, which compiled and ran with the correct test cases. Although I passed the challenge, I still know that I'm missing something (in terms of good programming practice). Another way I can think of is using ACCEPT without LINE SEQUENTIAL, since the following source mentions the behavior is unpredictable in that case:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQ2R2_9.5.1/com.ibm.etools.cbl.win.doc/topics/rlpsacce.htm

Comment: The link is for IBM's Rational Developer, using IBM's COBOL for Windows. What it is saying is that if SYSIN is used for both ACCEPT and for READ, then results will be unpredictable. Using *either* ACCEPT *or* READ will be unproblematic.

Comment: READ file-name NOT AT END something END-READ - did you have it like that? The END-READ is actually terminating the AT END/NOT AT END condition, not the READ itself.

Comment: See if this one helps at all: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28630294/1927206

Comment: I can't use GnuCOBOL, just the OpenCOBOL system

Comment: @BillWoodger the END-READ was giving me a lot of trouble with compilation, although your suggestion made sense to me

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to OPEN/CLOSE your SYSIN.

Just code:

```
ACCEPT MEAL-COST FROM SYSIN
```